# What is a function piecewise $\mathcal C^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, definition

The question may be very stupid, but what is a function that is piecewise $\mathcal C^1(\mathbb R)$ (i.e. an element of $\mathcal C^1_{piec}(\mathbb R)$) ? My suggestion are :

1. $f\in \mathcal C^0(\mathbb R)$ and $f'\in \mathcal C^0_{piece}(\mathbb R)$

or

2. $f\in \mathcal C_{piece}^0(\mathbb R)$ and $f'\in \mathcal C^0_{piece}(\mathbb R)$ ?

---

I know that $f\in \mathcal C^0_{piece}$ if $f$ has finitely many discontinuity, and discontinuities are finite, i.e.  if $f$ has a discontinuity at $a$, then $f(a)\in \mathbb R$ and $\lim_{x\to a^\pm}f(x)\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: $f(x)=|x|$ is one example. for the second case $f$ must be continuous in order for $f'$ to exist everywhere. If you don't mean that, $f(x)=|x|$, for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=1$ is one example

Comment: this doesn't answer my question ;-) @alphaomega

Comment: I would say it's a matter of definition and context  each time but i would guess it means the first one, for the reason i mentioned above.

Comment: But $\mathcal C^0(\mathbb R)\subset \mathcal C_{piece}^0(\mathbb R)$, so the first one is more restritive than the second one, so your example don't prove that the 1st one is the correct one... @alphaomega

Comment: I didn't say that my example proves that. I should delete my first comment anyways. I just assumed that you want to define $f'$ on all $\mathbb{R}$, and that would imply that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. That's why I would guess it is the first definition